# XeTeX hebrew problem with LyX

Tags: xetex, lyx, languages, hebrew

I am using LyX and trying to write in Hebrew using XeTeX. I get the following error messages:

```
undefined control sequence
Package polyglossia error
```

Is this a package I should get manually? I would mention that the problem is only with Hebrew fonts. If I am writing an English document it compiles fine and there is no problem.

**Edit**

Ok, I have written a MWE and exported it to a TeX file, I got the following:

```
%% LyX 2.0.0 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[english,hebrew]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{David}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{theorem}
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\newtheorem{theorem}{\R{משפט}}[section]
\AtBeginDocument{\make@lr\thetheorem}

\makeatother

\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\begin{document}
שלום עולם. זוהי דוגמה למסמך עברי\L{
\[
E=mc^{2}
\]
}זו הנוסחה המפורסמת של אינשטיין
\end{document}
```

The error messages are:

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
Fatal fontspec error: "cannot-use-pdftex"
The fontspec package requires either XeTeX or LuaTeX to function
You must change your typesetting engine to, e.g., "xelatex" or "lualatex"
instead of plain "latex" or "pdflatex"
See the fontspec documentation for further information
For immediate help type H <return>
...............................................  :    }
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) The message snippets you've posted do not look like the full error messages you will be getting: could you edit the question to include the full text? Also, a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) would be really useful.

Comment: Since this is LyX and not a TeX editor, these are the errors I'm getting. But if there is a way to see more detailed report I'd be happy to know

Comment: The errors will be in the `.log` file that TeX generates. They will include the text you've posted, but should be longer, for example naming the undefined control sequence.

Comment: Ok. I have written an example for a TeX file. Obviously it seems that XeTeX is not defined, but I am working usually with LyX, how can I make it define this properly?

Comment: If you have a full TeXLive distribution, `xelatex` should be installed already, and you should be able to choose `Document→Settings...→Fonts→Use non-TeX fonts (via XeTeX/LuaTeX)` in LyX to have your document compile with `xelatex`. If that doesn't work, you need to tell us more about how your TeX distribution was installed.

Comment: @AlanMunn: Could you add that as an answer? The other answer is a tad imprecise in calling XeTeX a _package_ and your answer is more self-contained.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a full TeXLive distribution, `xelatex` should be installed already, and you should be able to choose `Document→Settings...→Fonts→Use non-TeX fonts (via XeTeX/LuaTeX)` in LyX to have your document compile with `xelatex`. If that doesn't work, you need to tell us more about how your TeX distribution was installed.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using linux, you might have to install the XeTeX package first. Assuming you've done that, you probably want to follow the instructions to set up XeTeX in Lyx:

http://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/XeTeX

Once you set it up, you should be able to choose a hebrew font as Alan suggested.